# Springboot + Angular: attemptAuthentication request parameters null

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm making an Angular application as the frontend with a Springboot backend. I have set up SpringSecurity to handle logins and if I try it using Postman everything works, but when I try it using Angulars login, the "request.getParameter" calls always return me "null". I have tried changing it in several ways but the result is always the same.

The successful login return information about the user and a token.

Here is the Java part:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Lazy
    @Autowired
    CurrentUserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    @Autowired
    TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .headers().cacheControl().disable();
        http
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http
                .headers().xssProtection();
        http
                .exceptionHandling().and()
                .anonymous().and()
                .servletApi().and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
                .addFilterBefore(
                        new LoginFilter("/auth/login", authenticationManager(), tokenAuthService),
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                // Custom Token based authentication based on the header previously given to the
                // client
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTFilter(tokenAuthService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web
                .ignoring()
                // Allow anonymous resource requests
                .antMatchers("/favicon.ico");
    }
}
```

The LoginFilter does quite some things, but this is the minimum:

```java
public class LoginFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {
    private TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService;

    public LoginFilter(String urlMapping, AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, TokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService) {
        super(new AntPathRequestMatcher(urlMapping));
        setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        this.tokenAuthenticationService = tokenAuthenticationService;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException {
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        String password = request.getParameter("password");

        System.out.println("USERNAME: " + username + " - PASSWORD: " + password);
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        CurrentUser loggedUser = (CurrentUser) authentication.getPrincipal();
        ...
    }
}
```

Finally, the Angular form does some validations and calls to a service:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
    apiUrl: string = environment.API_URL;
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    login(data: LoginInterface): Observable<LoginResult> {
        const formData: string =
            'username=' + data.username + '&password=' + data.password;

        const httpOptions = {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            })
        };

        return this.http.post<LoginResult>(
            this.apiUrl + '/auth/login',
            formData,
            httpOptions
        );
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is it working with Postman?

Thanks!

Edit: As requested, here are the console details for the call in Chrome

Headers:

[image: Chrome headers]

Body:

[image: Chrome body data]

Postman headers:

[image: Postman headers]

Postman data:

[image: Postman data]

And here is Eclipse showing the null value that arrived:

[image: Eclipse showing null value]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do it by using `HttpParams` as the request body:

```js
login(data: LoginInterface): Observable<LoginResult> {
  const params = new HttpParams({
    fromObject: {
      username: data.username,
      password: data.password,
    },
  });
  return this.http.post<LoginResult>(this.apiUrl + '/auth/login', params, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    },
  });
}
```

Comment: Exactly the same thing, works from Postman but not from Angular :( Thanks anyway

Comment: Double check how Postman is doing it. What encoding, what content type, everything. You can even include a screenshot with the postman request here

Comment: I have added several screenshots to the original question, if there is anything else you would like please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: @IñigoGorosabel I updated my answer, can you have another look at it and see if it helps?

Comment: Still the same, I'm starting to think it will be something with the Java side because everything "looks good"... maybe some kind of redirection and Java loses the request? Just guessing...